# Call a different action when an action is called in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Say I have the `UsersController#show` action. It renders by default `users/show.html.erb`.

Now, I also have `ProductsController#index`, which receives a `Client` id and displays a table with all the products belonging to that client. It renders `products/index.html.erb`.

I would like to display this products list when a user wants to view `UsersController#show`. Here are some ideas of doing this:

- redirect `UsersController#show` to `ProductsController#index`;
- render `products/index.html.erb` in `UsersController#show`;
- copy `products/index.html.erb` to `users/show.html.erb`.

However, I feel these solutions aren't the best ones for doing what I want. is there any other better alternative? If not, which of the above should I follow?

Comment: make a partial with products list and render it whenever  you want

Comment: The products list has to get products from its action, based on some filters, and should also support pagination; not sure all of this can be done if using a partial.

Comment: Than make a class responsible for project searching and pagination and use it in UsersController

Comment: And what if I also need to view the products separately? Showing the products on a client's show page is just a shortcut from going to the client's show page, then clicking a link to see his products. It's some kind of default behavior.

Comment: You can use a ProductSearch class in products controller as well. It will be like additional representation layer.

Comment: Isn't it just overcomplicating myself? I was thinking more about using a default display for a controller action...don't know whether it is possible though.

Comment: using the partial is a common way for such things and class is for DRY

Answer (score 0):

Why not in the UsersController under the show method pass in the products related to that user? You could do something like

```
def show
  @products = Products.where(user_id: @user.id).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 3)
end
```

or if you are using devise I would do

```
def show
  @products = Products.where(user_id: current_user.id).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 3)
end
```

Then on the front hand you could render it simply by doing calling

To do the pagination I used the will_paginate gem